# Conditionally calculate difference between two columns on a sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet `allocations` dynamically capturing data:

- A widget ID
- B email of tester 1 assigned to the widget
- D widget rating by tester 1
- E email of tester 2 assigned to the widget
- G widget rating by tester 2
- I Differences in the ratings

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 45 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 50 | 0 |  |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 55 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 53 | 0 |  |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 75 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 25 | 0 |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 65 | `iris@company.com` | 0 | 85 | 0 |  |

(columns C, F, H are email sent flags, so irrelevant for now)

**What I want to happen**

In column I, I want Excel to calculate the difference between columns D and G, but only if both columns D and G have numerical values.

Sample output:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 45 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 50 | 0 | 5 |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 55 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 53 | 0 | 2 |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 75 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 25 | 0 |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 65 | `iris@company.com` | 0 | 85 | 0 | 20 |

**Not this**
Because I want column I to remain empty if not both of D and G have numerical values, and because I don't know upfront how many rows the sheet will end up having, I don't want to do something like `=ABS(G2-D2)` and copy it over all the way down.

Comment: you can use the `ISNUMBER` formula to check whether something is a number. So your logic is: If D and G are numbers, display the difference, else display empty string ("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MAP()` and `ISNUMBER()` to check whether the values in columns `D` & `G` are numberic or not.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `I2`

```
=MAP(D2:D6,G2:G6,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISNUMBER(x)*ISNUMBER(y),ABS(y-x),"")))
```

---

Also, `LAMBDA()` iteration is not required if you are in `MS365`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `I2`

```
=LET(
       a,D2:D6,
       b,G2:G6,
       IF(ISNUMBER(a)*ISNUMBER(b),ABS(b-a),""))
```

---

Assuming `Column A` will have entries till last row, then you could use the following formula.

```
=LET(
       a,MATCH(7^89,A:A),
       b,D2:INDEX(D:D,a),
       c,G2:INDEX(G:G,a),
       IF(ISNUMBER(b)*ISNUMBER(c),ABS(c-b),""))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
       a,LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A)),
       b,D2:INDEX(D:D,a),
       c,G2:INDEX(G:G,a),
       IF(ISNUMBER(b)*ISNUMBER(c),ABS(c-b),""))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
       b,DROP(FILTER(D:D,A:A<>""),1),
       c,DROP(FILTER(G:G,A:A<>""),1),
       IF(ISNUMBER(b)*ISNUMBER(c),ABS(c-b),""))
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks Mayukh! How should I adjust this if I don't know upfront how many rows this sheet will have?

Comment: @OC2PS ah knew that, you would have that same problem, so which column should i take will have all data till last row. May i assume that as `Column A`

Comment: Yes, let's say column A is the primary key, so to say.

Comment: @OC2PS updated, i have added few possible ways.