# Dynamically update a sheet based on values received in another sheet (within same workbook) from a form

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, microsoft-forms

I am using Office 365. In order to collect info from forms in a live Excel sheet, I created a new Excel Online workbook/ file (basically within the browser, logged into Office 365, went to Excel and "Create New" which created an Excel file in OneDrive) and did `Insert > Forms` to create a new Microsoft Forms form.

The Microsoft Forms form is intended to collect information from users within my organization (i.e. sign in is required to fill up the form). The information collected is widget ratings.

Context:
A bunch of widgets are assigned to colleagues to test and rate. A specific widget (identified by `widget_id`) is always assigned to exactly 2 testers. Each tester can be assigned any number of widgets. Once a tester has rated a widget, they input their rating via the Microsoft Forms form mentioned above.

The info collected via the form is as following:

- `email` of respondent (collected automatically).
- `datetime` of response (collected automatically).
- `widget_id` of the rated widget (selected by respondent from a dropdown).
- `rating` of the widget determined by the respondent (numerical entry within a set range, e.g. 1 ... 100 )

So, in my Excel workbook's forms sheet, it appears as:
Let's say the Forms submissions sheet is called `Form 1`.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email | date | widget_id | rating |
| `jack@company.com` | 2023-04-23 | 990236 | 65 |
| `mack@company.com` | 2023-04-23 | 990236 | 75 |
| `iris@company.com` | 2023-04-23 | 990003 | 50 |
| `jack@company.com` | 2023-04-24 | 990235 | 45 |

I have another sheet `allocations` with 6 relevant columns which has information on which testers have been allocated to each widget:

- A widget ID
- B email of tester 1 assigned to the widget
- D widget rating by tester 1
- E email of tester 2 assigned to the widget
- G widget rating by tester 2
- Columns C, F, and H-J are irrelevant for this issue

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference | average |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |

**What I want to happen**

As various testers submit their forms, Excel should populate column D or G (as appropriate) of `allocations` sheet, depending on the widget id and tester email. In other words, I want Excel to copy over the ratings from the `Form 1` sheet to the appropriate place in the more understandable `allocations` sheet.

In other words,
the moment, the data row appears in `Form 1` sheet,
Excel should look for the `widget_id` from this row in `allocations` sheet.
Further, Excel should check whether the `email` from this row in `Form 1` sheet matches `email1` in `allocations` sheet or `email2` in `allocations` sheet in the row in which this `widget_id is found in` allocations`.   If it matches` email1`then copy the`rating`from this row in`allocations`sheet to`rating1`in`allocations`sheet, if it matches`email2`then copy the`rating`to`rating2`.

So, in our example `allocations` sheet would look like

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference | average |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 45 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 | 75 | `jack@company.com` | 0 | 65 | 0 |  |  |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 | 50 | 0 |  |  |

Comment: For Rating One: `=XLOOKUP(A2:A6&"|"&B2:B6,C2:C5&"|"&A2:A5,D2:D5,"")` For Rating Two : `=XLOOKUP(A2:A6&"|"&E2:E6,C2:C5&"|"&A2:A5,D2:D5,"")`

Comment: @mayukh-bhattacharya To clarify: Rating 1 and 2 are not actually ordered ratings ... i.e. there isn't an actual First and Second rating... just two ratings, and either rater could fill up his/her form before the other ...

Comment: Did you try the formula yet? the first formula will go into cell `D2` of allocations sheet while the other one in `G2`

Comment: is it not working for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. In any case, the lookup value would be in the current sheet (allocations) column B (or column E as the case may be), and the lookup array to match inside would be in Form 1 sheet column A, right?

Comment: To explain his formula (since it does work, I just tested it with your example data): `A2:A6 & " | " & B2:B6` is the key you want to look up with (he wants to fill in the entire column in one go, hence the A2:A6 instead of just A2) and then you do the same thing with the lookup range: `C2:C5 & " | " & A2:A5`, what @MayukhBhattacharya did forget is the values being on the different sheet so formula would be `=XLOOKUP(A2:A6&" | " &B2:B6,Form1!C2:C5 & " | " & Form1!A2:A5,Form1!D2:D5,"")` (adjust where needed) or `=XLOOKUP(A2&" | " &B2,Form1!C2:C5 & " | " & Form1!A2:A5,Form1!D2:D5,"")` for one .

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes correct sir, I forgot to refer the sheet name while i was using the formula in one worksheet where look up value was in cells F & G & I respectively.

Comment: Understood. So, I tried `=XLOOKUP(A2:A1000&" | " &B2:B1000,forms!C2:C1000 & " | " & forms!A2:A1000,forms!D2:D1000,"")` in D2 and `=XLOOKUP(A2:A6&" | " &E2:E6,forms!C2:C5 & " | " & forms!A2:A5,forms!D2:D5,"")` in G2, and it works. The use of row 1000 because I don't know beforehand how many rows will actually be there. The problem is D7:D1000 now have the value `0` though I want them to be empty. How do I address that?

Comment: While I'm pretty sure there's a more elegant way to fix this, `=IF(ISEMPTY(A2:A1000,"",XLOOKUP(A2:A1000&" | " &B2:B1000,forms!C2:C1000 & " | " & forms!A2:A1000,forms!D2:D1000,""))` should do it.

Comment: @OC2PS i think have already posted about the last row in your last post. Use this in cell D2 of `allocations sheet` `=LET(
       x,MATCH(7^89,A:A),
       y,A2:INDEX(A:A,x),
       z,B2:INDEX(B:B,x),
       XLOOKUP(y&"|"&z,'Form 1'!C:C&"|"&'Form 1'!A:A,'Form 1'!D:D,""))` and in cell `G2` `=LET(
       x,MATCH(7^89,A:A),
       y,A2:INDEX(A:A,x),
       z,E2:INDEX(E:E,x),
       XLOOKUP(y&"|"&z,'Form 1'!C:C&"|"&'Form 1'!A:A,'Form 1'!D:D,""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data till the last row and produce the desired outcome, just like i had posted in comments, please refer the following formulas.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(
     x,MATCH(7^89,A:A),
     y,A2:INDEX(A:A,x),
     z,B2:INDEX(B:B,x),
     XLOOKUP(y&"|"&z,'Form 1'!C:C&"|"&'Form 1'!A:A,'Form 1'!D:D,""))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=LET(
     x,MATCH(7^89,A:A),
     y,A2:INDEX(A:A,x),
     z,E2:INDEX(E:E,x),
     XLOOKUP(y&"|"&z,'Form 1'!C:C&"|"&'Form 1'!A:A,'Form 1'!D:D,""))
```

---

To get data till last row, i had posted the other alternatives in your last post: [**Conditionally calculate difference between two columns on a sheet**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528963/8162520)

---

**[Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjH80ByMl_pjozb_S?e=j7jYNh)**